# Formula for numerating the elements of the set

Tags: combinatorics

Is there a formula for numerating the elements of the set
$$
D = \{ (i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_k): 1 \leq i_1 <i_2 < \ldots <i_k \leq n \}
$$
(here $ n, k $ are positive integers, $ n> k $; $ i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_k $ are positive integers),
that is, a formula for the one-to-one correspondence between $D$ and a finite interval of $\mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: Have you tried to come up with your own?

Answer (score 0):

We will define $f_{n,k}:D_{n,k}\to\mathbb{N}$ inductively, where $D_{n,k}$ represents the set you describe for a particular choice of $n$ and $k$.  Of course, $k\leq n$.

When $k=0$, then $f_{n,0}(())=0\in[0,0]$ works, where $()$ is the empty tuple.

When $n=k$, then $f_{n,k}(1,2,\dots,n)=0\in[0,0]$ works also.

Now suppose $k>0$ and $n>k$.  Define $f_{n,k}(i_1,\dots,i_k)=f_{i_k-1, k-1}(i_1,\dots,i_{k-1}) + \sum_{j=k}^{i_k-1}\binom{j}{k-1}$, whose range is $[0,\binom{n}{k}-1]$.  The idea is that incrementing $i_k$ by one will make the sum increase by the size of the range of $f_{i_k-1, k-1}$.

This is only one possible encoding scheme, surely a more elegant one exists.